# How to release a secure MMA-NB/CDF with restrictions/locks to the back-end code visibility

Tags: notebook-security

*Intention* is to distribute demonstration files just like [Wolfram Demonstrations](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/) (mainly dynamic manipulations with assisting textual explanations based off on Numerical Methods course lectures).

If distributing as notebook/cdf is not practical, web-apps is also another option to try. Regardless would like to lock all back-end code visibility from the user.

Please advise.

Comment: Just copy the output cell produced by the `Manipulate` expression into a new notebook and distribute the copied stuff. If the `Manipulate` has been written so that its code is self-contained, i.e., doesn't depend on code in other cells to run, you will get what you want.

Comment: Please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1571/5478 and related topics. CloudCDF could be the best but then you need to take care about $CloudCreditsAvailable.

Comment: Might want to check Demonstrations by D. Barnhart from his Optica work. My recollection is they did some encoding. Not sure it was bullet-proof though.

Comment: I don't consider `Encode` a security measure but maybe it just fits your need: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86674/5478

Comment: See [How to Encrypt Your Code for Deployment](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=88&v=596) for a CDF option.